# How to improve the hotkeys Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right?

Tags: text-editors, hotkeys, text-editing, selection

I'm just wondering if anyone of you figured out a way to improve these bindings or use them together with other bindings to make go through lines of text faster/easier.

namely the problem i'm facing is that e.g.:

```
<!-- <ui:composition template="/templates/someNameingSpecialtemplate.xhtml" attrib="burp"> -->
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> will always only move one character in a little bit more special characters i.e.  `<!--` and will not stop at all for the big-letter changes `someNameingSpecialtemplate`

Is there some better solution something you guys thought of? An improved set of rules for when the cursor stops? different hotkeys which add well to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> (e.g. naively - move 15 characters to the left)?

BTW, I am using eclipse as my editor, but this applies generally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a famous text editor called Vim which defines many motion commands. Some of those have been worked into [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/documentation/?page=3) which emulates this legendary text-editor. The link I gave you lists some supported commands from Vim, but the list will probably not be very meaningful to you. There is a link on that page that will take you to the Vim documentation, but that too will probably be too much to begin with.

I suggest you get your hands on a copy of vim (for windows) and run the [vimtutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049316/how-do-you-run-vim-in-windows) interactive intro. This will give you some idea of how you can hop around in the file with commands such as w,e,b,f which is roughly what you are looking for.

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, and the moitons are awesome. Vrapper seems exactly like what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad you liked it. I find it useful too, although now days I've converted to eclimd which integrates eclipe _into_ Vim :)